How to merge branches into main in GitHub?
Learning my way around GitHub and have gotten stuck when it comes to consolidating uploaded documents.
After uploading my documents to the GitHub repository (using the click-and-drag feature), I see that each upload appears as a separate branch.
How do I merge the upload branches into the main?
Inserting a screen shot in case it helps.


Open the "Pull requests" tab and merge the PRs there. When you drag and drop a file it shows two options: "Commit directly to the main branch" and "Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request." In the future select the first one to skip the pull request + merge part.

@GuyIncognito Ok - so for each of the four branches, I click on Pull Request and merge to main?

The Pull requests tab is per project, not per branch. The screenshot shows there's one pull request active at the moment, presumably one of the four branches. For all the others you'll have to make new pull requests manually.

@GuyIncognito Ok. For example, if I click on the patch-1 branch in the pulldown menu, I see a message "This branch is 3 commits behind main".  What exactly does this mean? The whole process seems unnecessarily complicated. After clicking and dragging the document into the repo, why are further actions required?

Further actions are not required if you select the "commit directly" option when uploading files. That said, people usually don't use Github via the web interface. The usual workflow happens on your local computer with git console commands or standalone software like Github Desktop. The web interface is deliberately simplistic and geared towards reading the repos instead of changing them.

@GuyIncognito After dragging a document into the desired repo folder, a "Propose changes" button appears - I can commit to main or create a new branch. However, I cannot commit to the main because it is protected. Admin approval reuired?

Ah ok it's not your personal repo. Then you'll just have to make pull requests for the uploads and either merge them yourself or if you don't have access to that either, assign someone to the pull request who can do it.

@GuyIncognito I get a little confused when it comes to Pull Requests - is a Pull Request the same as merging a branch to main?

No, it's a request for someone to merge the branch to another branch (typically main.) That "someone" can be the same person who creates the pull request.
